# managing trac users

Tags: user-accounts, trac

There is a legacy [`trac`](http://trac.edgewall.org/) - a web bug tracking software - installed in my company, and I have started to maintain it. Although I have Googled the subject thoroughly, and I have full admin access, I couldn't figure out how to add or remove users from the system.

Any ideas?

Comment: You provided a link, which is useful, but could you explain a bit in your question what _trac_ is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) can be configured to authenticate using LDAP, [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html) or a user list for authentication for users.

If Trac is configured to use an internal user list, i.e. it is running under it's own internal webserver (called 'tracd') then a simple text file controls user access and is normally found under the trac project directory. See http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#UsingAuthentication

The above link will be useful to look at regardless of the authentication method.

If when you log in to Trac, you use your normal Windows login credentials then it is configured for LDAP authentication and you don't usually need to add individual users manually.

Also when initially configuring Trac, you do need to set up an admin user which you have to do via the command line (it sounds like this has already been done):

```
trac-admin /path/to/my/project
permission add <username> TRAC_ADMIN
```